# Dissipate blizzard?

Tags: science-based, technology, chemistry

Is it possible to dissipate a blizzard with a chemical component? Or maybe with a special machine?

There are no limits here except that the technology is gunpowder-renaissance-Napoleonic technology.

Resources are unlimited.

Comment: It's "Renaissance". That's important for anyone Googling it.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's annoying when there's no feedback about how can I improve the question.

Comment: I quite agree with that etiquette. Perhaps, in this case  it is related to the Close nomination reasons? "Too broad" and "off topic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible to dissipate a blizzard?**

If you're talking about getting rid of a blizzard that's already in progress, with *unlimited* resources it would technically be possible but it's not going to be pretty. The short version is that it's in the same ballpark as getting rid of a hurricane.

First, think about what a blizzard really is - it's not a localized phenomenon happening in just a small area. A blizzard is a strong storm covering a large area. One way to "dissipate" a blizzard is to heat up the area enough that you will have a downpour instead of a blizzard.

The amount of energy required to accomplish it is absolutely ridiculous and well beyond the reach of pre-nuclear technology. If you haven't read [XKCD's snow removal question](https://what-if.xkcd.com/130/), you should do so. Here's a relevant picture:

[image]

> The nuclear reactor on an aircraft carrier, for example, produces less than 200 megawatts. To melt snow in front of your car, you'd need three of those.

This is what it takes to melt 1 inch of snow covering a 67m^2 area each second (clearing the path for a car going at 55mph). A strong blizzard can drop 2-4 inches of snow per hour, so consider a more moderate blizzard that drops 1 inch of snow per hour. That means this would be enough energy to keep an area of 0.24km^2 clear of snow if you're expending it constantly while the blizzard is on.

[Gunpowder has 3MJ/kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density) of energy, so you'd need about 200kg of gunpowder *per second* to get that much energy. Over the course of a 2 hour storm, you'd use up 1440 metric tons of gunpowder to keep a small portion of the area affected by the storm clear of snow. Additionally, the water is still there and we've done nothing about the wind.

And that's assuming that somehow the gunpowder isn't getting wet from the storm, and that 100% of the energy released by the gunpowder goes toward melting the snow. Neither of those are actually reasonable assumptions.

There is a lot more energy in a blizzard than you probably think.

Comment: 1440 metric tons of gunpowder on such a small area is akin to a small nuke.  In this case, the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: @Green In this case it's a small nuke exploded over the course of two hours, so it won't be quite so devastating.

Comment: true, it is less devastating.  Despite the longer duration of the energy delivered, something is going to get cooked.  .24km^2 is about 59 acres or the size of a small residential subdivision. I worked it out to ~3.5 grams of gunpowder per meter squared per second.  Any surface not covered in snow or cooled by wind will basically stare a bright light for two hours.  Ouch. If such a structure could be constructed to broadly deliver that kind of energy...it would make more sense to just build an awning instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a huge (tens of thousands) number of windmills like this proposal to attenuate the strength of hurricanes like this [Stanford proposal](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2014/february/hurricane-winds-turbine-022614.html).  The windmills, when connected to a load, will extract energy from the blizzard thereby decreasing it's strength. Maybe the load will be two friction plates pressed together underwater to generate steam for heating.

Comment: In the strict definition of 'dissipate', no, large numbers of windmills don't technically do that as they are only able to attenuate or diminish the strength of a blizzard, not scatter it.  I suppose in special circumstances they could suck enough energy out of a small part of a storm to split the storm into two tracks.

Comment: My reference to windmills was intentional as electricity generating wind turbines didn't appear till 1887 and I have no idea what the maintenance costs on a Napolean era windmill would cost.